# gets undefined when i call my param in backend node controller

Tags: node.js, express

Here is the request type:

```
interface IgetProductsByGenderRequest extends express.Request {
  readonly params: Readonly<{ gender: string; }>;
}
```

When I'm using `req.params.gender` I get `undefined`.

When I'm using `req.params` I get the param but in object and I want to get it in a var.

My backend controller:

```
const getProductsByGender = async (
    req: IgetProductsByGenderRequest,
    res: IgetProductsByGenderResponse
) => {
    console.log(req.params)
    ServerGlobal.getInstance().logger.info(
        `<getProductsByGender>: Start processing request filtered by and gender ${req.params.gender}`
    );

    if (
        !ServerGlobal.getInstance().isValidGenderValue(+req.params.gender)
    ) {
        ServerGlobal.getInstance().logger.error(
            `<getProductsByGender>: Failed to get products because of invalid gender filtered by gender ${req.params.gender}`
        );

        res.status(400).send({
            success: false,
            message: "Please provide valid gender",
        });
        return;
    }

    try {
        const products = await ProductDB.find({ gender: +req.params.gender });

        ServerGlobal.getInstance().logger.info(
            `<getProductsByGender>: Successfully got the products filtered by gender ${req.params.gender}`
        );

        res.status(200).send({
            success: true,
            message: "Successfully retrieved products",
            data: products.map((product) => ({
                id: product.id as string,
                gender: {
                    value: product.gender,
                    label: ServerGlobal.getInstance().getGenderLabel(product.gender)!,
                },
                title: product.title,
                description: product.description,
                price: product.price,
                imageFilename: product.imageFilename,
            })),
        });
        return;
    } catch (e) {
        ServerGlobal.getInstance().logger.error(
            `<getProductsByGender>: Failed to get products filtered by gender ${req.params.gender} because of server error: ${e}`
        );

        res.status(500).send({
            success: false,
            message: "Server error",
        });
        return;
    }
};
```

How can I access the gender param?

Comment: So where's the code where you actually use this? Where is `req.params` set? _By default Express should add that for the URL query parameters._

Comment: in get request in the backend controller @KelvinSchoofs

Comment: We can't help you with your code if we don't see the code where it's going wrong.

Comment: @KelvinSchoofs edited. might help you to understand better

Comment: @KelvinSchoofs i can paste the controller, im not sure it will help

Comment: @KelvinSchoofs added

Comment: Using any middleware (that inferferes with `req.params`)? How do you use `getProductsByGender ` when declaring your route?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235805/discussion-between-blablalbla3233-and-kelvin-schoofs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest reading the documentation regarding [routing](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) and regarding [query parameters](http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#req.query).

You have `req.query`, which is for query parameters, e.g. `/some/path?myVariable=test` would have `req.query.myVariable === 'test'`.

You also have `req.params` which is when you're using URL parameters, e.g. `/some/path/:id` would have `req.params.id === 'test'` when the user visits `/some/path/test`.

Make sure you are using/accessing the correct one, as it's easy to make mistakes in this regards. *And of course watch out for typos, although you should've spotted that with your `console.log(req.params)` statement.*

Comment: req.params - returns { category: '2' }. what i would like to know is how to get the gender value only.

Comment: That should just be `req.params.gender`? Doesn't that work?

Comment: thats what returns undefined

Comment: I just noticed you changed your comment from `{ gender: 2 }` to `{ category: '2' }`. There's no gender present? Like I said in a comment on the question, it depends on how you define your route. _And if you're using query parameters, you need to use `req.query` instead._

Comment: really sorry. but i didnt notice the 'category'. i just needed to change my route to /;gender. thx for everything.